# is this function infinitely differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be an infinitely differentiable function defined on real line $R$.
Assuming $f(0)=0$, define $g(x)=f(x)/x$ if $x$ is not zero, and $g(0)=f'(0)$. My question is whether $g$ is infinitely differetiable?
A further question is that if $f$ is assumed analytic on real line $R$, and $g$ is defined as above, then would  $g$ be analytic?

---

It is evident that $g$ is continous since 
$$lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(f(x)-f(0))/(x-0)=f'(0)=g(0)$$.

Comment: Please note that f(0)=0 is assumed.

Comment: sorry I didn’t see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $$ f(x) = x f'(0) + \int^x_0 (x- u) f''(u)\, du.$$
(Check this by differentiating - but the integral is 'the' (an?) integral form of the remainder of the T.S.)
Make the substitution $u = t x$... to conclude that your $g$ is infinitely differentiable.

And yes, $g$ is analytic if $f$ is: write the power series out...

Comment: @stephenkk BTW, this argument (if I haven't screwed it up!)  turns up in differential geometry to calculate Lie brackets....

Comment: I check this integral form and find it correct, but I don't know how to use substitution to show $g$ is infinitely differentiable? could you elaborate further?

Comment: After substitution of $u=tx$ (treating $x$ as 'constant'), the original integral equals $$ x^2  \int_0^1 (1 -t) f''(tx) \,dt.$$ So you can divide out by $x$ to get $$ g(x)  = f'(0) +x \cdot \text{ something infinitely differentiable in $x$}.$$ Okay?

Comment: this technique is really impressing.

Comment: As I implied - it's obviously not my creation...

Answer (score 0):

no, think about the case of $f(x)=e^x-1$
if $f^{(n)}(0)\neq0$, then $g^{(n)}(x)$can't be differentiated at $x\neq0$

Comment: For nonzero $x$, $g$ is infinitely differentiable since $ f $,$1/x$ are infinitely differentiable around  $x$.